# $n,m$ symmetry in the determinants of block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

This question is related to [Determinant of block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1307671/122782).

---

$n \times n$ block tridiagonal matrix $A_{nm}$ constructed from $m\times m$ blocks $J_m,I_m$,

\begin{align} 
A_{nm} 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
J_n & I_n & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ 
I_m & J_m & I_m & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & I_m & J_m  & I_m & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots & 0 \\ 
0 & \cdots & \cdots & I_m & J_m & I_m \\ 
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & I_m & J_m 
\end{bmatrix}
_{n\times n}
,
\end{align}

where $I_m$ is $m\times m$ identity matrix,
and $J_m$ is a tridiagonal matrix with ones on the three diagonals.

\begin{align} 
\end{align}

**The question:**
is this a known property or
is there a simple way to prove that

\begin{align} 
\det(A_{nm})&=\det(A_{mn})
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$?

---

Statement \eqref{1} agrees for small $n,m$, for example this is a $9\times9$
matrix with elements $m_{ij}=\det(A_{ij}),\ i,j=1,\dots,9$:

\begin{align} 
M_{9} 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0&  -1&  -1&     0&       1&        1&        0&       -1 \\
 0& -3&   0&   5&     0&      -7&        0&        9&        0 \\
-1&  0&  -7&  -9&     0&      -7&      119&        0&      369 \\
-1&  5&  -9&   0&    55&      29&      279&      -95&        0 \\
 0&  0&   0&  55&     0&   -1183&        0&        0&        0 \\
 1& -7&  -7&  29& -1183&    2197&     -791&    28672&  -165271 \\
 1&  0& 119& 279&     0&    -791&   -34391&        0& -2733921 \\
 0&  9&   0& -95&     0&   28672&        0& -4002939&        0 \\
-1&  0& 369&   0&     0& -165271& -2733921&        0&        0 
\end{bmatrix}
,
\end{align}

where the first and second row/column shows an easy pattern,
but the other
(as well as a main diagonal) are not recognized as a known
[integer sequence](http://oeis.org/).

For some reason, the choice of $n=5$ of $m=5$ result in seven zeros of nine.

Obviously, matrices $A_{nm}$ and $A_{mn}$ are of the same size, $mn\times mn$ elements
and it's easy to show that they have the same number of $1$s.

As it is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308768/122782),
$\det(A_{nm})$ boils down to the determinant of the $m\times m$ matrix,
for example

\begin{align}
\det(43)&=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
4&6&5 \\
6&9&6\\
5&6&4
\end{matrix}
\right|=-9
,\\
\det(34)&=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
2&3&3&1\\
3&5&4&3\\
3&4&5&3\\
1&3&3&2
\end{matrix}
\right|=-9
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues are given exactly by $f(\theta_1,\theta_2)=1+2\cos(\theta_1)+2\cos(\theta_2)$ where $\theta_1=i\pi/(m+1)$ $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $\theta_2=j\pi/(n+1)$ $j=1,\ldots,n$.