# Calculating the characteristic polynomial of a block tridiagonal Toeplitz Symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I am trying to calculate the characteristic polynomial of a block tridiagonal matrix and I need some help. This matrix is a representation of a tight-binding Hamiltonian of a finite grid of graphene, it'll be really cool to get the analytical eigenenergies of the system to improve the numerical methods.

$t_1$ is the intra cell hopping, $t_2$ is the inter hopping along x direction and $t_3$ is the inter hopping along y direction. The structure of the Hamiltonian is as follows:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta & T & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
T^t & \Delta & T & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & T^t & \Delta & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & T^t & \Delta
\end{bmatrix}$$

where:

- $\Delta$ is a $n \times n$ tridiagonal matrix with zeros on the main diagonal, and the upper and lower diagonals alternate with $t_1$ and $t_2$, starting with $t_1$.

$$\Delta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & t_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
t_1 & 0 & t_2 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & t_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & t_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

- $T$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with zeros on the main diagonal, and the first lower diagonal is all $t_3$.

$$T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
t_3 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & t_3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & t_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

- $T^t$ is simply the transpose of $T$.

I am looking for an effective way to calculate the characteristic polynomial of this block tridiagonal matrix. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

I already know how to calculate the characteristic polynomial of $\Delta$ and obviously $T$ if it helps.

Comment: It is also symmetric and block Toeplitz, right?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1307671/339790)

Comment: i think it’s not the same because the upper and lower blocks are not Identity matrices so i can’t use the easy trick to block determinants they use there. But yes, it is symmetric and Toeplitz

Comment: Then you can include Toeplitz in the question. Do not forget the title